# Kendo: Grid Column Link with 2 field values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Using Kendo UI with MVC 4:

I have a Grid with columns. I need to create a link from 2 fields in the model the grid is bound to. "Country" and "State"

```
          columns.Bound(p => p.Country)
              .ClientTemplate(
                  "<a href='" + Url.Action("Detach", "Edit")">Detach</a>"
               );
```

How do I add /Country/State to the URL? These values come from the grid's bound model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a template referencing the fields:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Country)
          .ClientTemplate(
              "<a href='" + Url.Action("Detach", "Edit") + "/#= Country #/#= State #'">Detach</a>"
           );
```

Check this [How do I use action links?](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-use-action-links?)